# Verilog synthesis is giving me an error that I don't understand

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I am getting this error when synthesizing my code, but I don't know what it means. It reads:

> Error- net "Count[0] or a directly connected net is driven by more
> than one source and not all drivers are three state.

It says the same errors for vectors count[0] - count[4] as well as for my `load` and `k` values. The code is my representation of an SPI Master. The SPI master has an instantiation of a shift register that is used to push out information.

```
module SPIMaster(output reg SCLK, CS, MOSI, 
input EN, CLK, MISO, 
input [7:0] m_data);
    wire master_out;
    reg [4:0] count;
    wire [7:0] data_buff;
    wire SCLK1;
    reg master_in, c_sw, k, state, load;
    shiftReg register_out (master_out, data_buff, load, (~SCLK), master_in, m_data);
    assign SCLK1 = (~c_sw) | CLK;
    always@(posedge CLK) begin
        if(state) begin
            if (k == 1) begin
                state <= 0;
                c_sw <= 0;
                CS <= 1;
                count <= 0;
                k <= 0;
                load <= 0;
            end
            else begin
                state <= 1;
                c_sw <= 1;
                CS <= 0;
            end
        end
        else begin
            if (EN == 1) begin
                state <= 1;
                c_sw <= 1;
                CS <= 0;
                count <= 0;
                k <= 0;
                load <= 1;
            end
            else begin
                state <= 0;
                c_sw <= 0;
                CS <= 1;
                count <= 0;
                k <= 0;
                load <= 0;
            end
        end
    end
    always@(posedge SCLK1) begin
        if (CS == 0) master_in <= MISO;
        if (count == 7) begin
            load <= 0;
        end
        else if (count == 15)begin
            load <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            load <= 1;
        end
    end
    always@(negedge SCLK1) begin
        if (count == 23) k <= 1;
        else k <= 0;
        if (CS == 0) begin
            MOSI <= master_out;
            count <= count + 1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not adhere to good synthesis coding practices because you assign to `count` from 2 different `always` blocks and those 2 blocks are triggered by different clock signals.  You should make all assignments to `count` from the same `always` block.

The same is true of `load` and `k`.